# Automatic timezone in Xubuntu (xfce + geoclue)

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, timezone, geolocation

Is there any way to set system timezone automatically in Xubuntu 18.04? I see that geoclue-2.0 is installed in my system and seem to be properly configured, but there is no "Automatic" option in Date/Time system configuration and in xfce-panel applets (Clock, Weather, etc.)

- xfce 4.12
- geoclue-2.0
- xfce4-weather-plugin 0.8.10

Any points to relevant resources (forum discussions, mailing list threads, open issues) would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm using kubuntu, but maybe we have the same issue, ubuntu's searches point to this page: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/privacy-location.html.en
but that menù is not in my settings. Did you solve? How?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of your desktop environment, time synchronisation can be enabled from the terminal if it already isn't by using

```
sudo timedatectl set-ntp on
```

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I was not entirely clear, but my question is not about **time** synchronization, it is about setting **timezone** automatically according to location information provided e.g. by geoclue, and using this automatic timezone system-wide as well as in xfce panel applets.

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu 20.04, I can enable the location service first, then enable the automatic timezone.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.system.location enabled true
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.datetime automatic-timezone true
```